# How to define generalized Selector method

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector

My question could be wrongly portrayed but following explanation will make you understand what I am looking for.

I have written following method to add a done button over the keyboard. And since I have many screens where user has to enter the value via keyboard so I want to write this method at one single place in order to avoid redundancy. I have written one class in which I have define the following method and I and I am passing textfield and object of UIViewController as parameters. I have to add selector   method which will be called when user will tap on the Done Button. The problem is where to define the selector in order to resign the Keyboard?

```
- (void)addDoneButtonOnToolBar:(UITextField*)objUITextField objViewController:(UIViewController*)objViewController
{
    //UIToolbar *keyboardDoneButtonView = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,SCREEN_WIDTH, 40)];
    UIToolbar *keyboardDoneButtonView = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    [keyboardDoneButtonView sizeToFit];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:objViewController action:@selector(doneKeyboardClicked:)];
    [keyboardDoneButtonView setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:doneButton, nil]];
    objUITextField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardDoneButtonView;
}
```

So unltimately, where to define "doneKeyboardClicked:"?

Comment: where is your `objUITextField`? You already defined `target:objViewController`, so it should be in `objViewController`.

Comment: I have declared and defined this method in separate class where I am passing textfield and object of View controller as parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in a category:

```
@implementation UIViewController (Selector)

- (void)doneKeyboardClicked:(UIBarButtonItem *)item {
    [self.view endEditing:true];
}

@end
```

Comment: It is giving me warning as I didn't defined the "doneKeyboardClicked" in that class

Answer (score 0):

I think the smart solution is to use a subclass of UITextField that sets the inputAccessoryView on init and has the selector doneKeyboardClicked as this:

```
-(void) doneKeyboardClicked:(UIBarButtonItem*)item {
    [self resignFirstResponder];
}
```